# ImageMagick - Order of command option 'Alpha Activate' used along with resize or flatten causes blank image in Version 7

Tags: imagemagick

We are migrating from ImageMagick 6 to ImageMagick 7, but using the same command line option used in version 6 is now giving a blank image in version 7. The command used is

> convert "C:\Imagemagick\beige.png" -alpha Activate -scale 640x640
> "C:\Imagemagick\Out\Zoom.jpg"

The input "beige.png" does not have an alpha channel. But if I input an image with alpha channel, it creates a file with valid results. Also, if I set the option "-alpha Activate" after scale operation it gives a valid result. Do we need to consider any order while setting the alpha for ImageMagick 7 version?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? A PNG may or may not have an alpha channel. If it has one, it will be activated already. You then write a JPEG which won't have an alpha channel. So what are you trying to do, please? And what v7 command are you using?

Comment: I guess you probably want `-alpha set`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am using the same command in v7. I tried "magick" instead of "convert" but with same result. I do not know whether the input will have alpha channel or not, but since in v6 it gave a valid image, I was expecting a similar one in v7.

Comment: According to https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_activate they behave differently. "Alpha Activate/Deactivate
enables and disables the alpha channel, respectively, with persistence. This is like on/off in Imagemagick 6. In Imagemagick 7, -alpha off will remove the alpha channel permanently such that -alpha on will not re-enable it."

Comment: @fmw42 Its again confusing as the https://imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_off says the -alpha off "does not actually delete or destroy the alpha channel attached to the image, it just turns off any effect that channel has on the image"

Comment: Yes, a bit confusing. In Imagemagick 6, it does not destroy the alpha channel. But in Imagemagick 7, it does.  IM 6, generally ignores the alpha channel in most processing. But Imagemagick 7, treats the alpha just like the other channels when doing processing. Bu default, IM 6, processes RGB, but IM 7 processes RGBA. This was a change when they developed the new Imagemagick 7. So when using convert you are using IM 6 and when using magick you are using IM 7.  Do not use magick convert. That is nearly the same as convert.